# Advantages of a cascode

Tags: transistors, cascode

The diagram of the cascode was taken from "the Art of electronics":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flPHBX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The claim is that in this configuration they practically eliminate the Early effect in Q1, but for me this does not solve the overall problem, since they just pass the defect to Q2, which now will suffer from this effect. Moreover the compliance is slightly reduced.

The question is, why would this scheme be more stable against changes in the beta factor?

Comment: Cascodes are typically used to reduce the *Miller effect* and thus improve the bandwidth.

Comment: Have a look here:https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Op_I3Ke7px0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q2 will not suffer from the early effect as it is being driven by the current from Q1 so th effects will be negligible.

All that will happen if the Vce increases is that the Vbe will drop slightly and so increase the voltage on Q1 by a few millivolts.

The overall effect for the cascade will be greatly reduced by many orders of magnitude.

Have you any calculations or measurements that indicate your circuit still suffers from the Early effect.

As @null mentions the Miller effect is also reduced.

This type of circuit is commonly used in video amplifiers or CRT oscilloscope output stages where a high voltage swing with wide bandwidth is needed.